# displaying user online status on steam

Tags: php, steam

I want to display the user status (if they are online, offline, busy, etc).

My code :

```
  <p class="category"><?php echo $steamprofile['personastate']; ?></p>
```

When I use the above code it only display numbers, not the status label ("online","offline")

This is what I get:

> The user's current state, 1 - Online, 2 - Busy, 3 - Away, 4 - Snooze, 5 - looking to trade, 6 - looking to play

If user is online it displays 1, offline 2.

I am using [steamauth library](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication
):

How I can covert the numbers to the status "online" or offline etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option to you is to create a local array where you put your pair id => Status, so you have something like this

```
$statuses = array (1 => 'Online',2 => 'Busy' , 3 => ...); //Complete with all avaiable statuses
echo $statuses[$steamprofile['personalstate']];
```

This piece of code should make the trick

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as the right answer then, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try Use list , and set values with indexes as it is showing in your case, than whatever the number come just match it and show the appropriate Status ,

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
  list.Add();
```

and than match index wise in in if else .